# Error using SimpleImpute in scikite-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I use sklearn to impute some time-series which include NaN values. At the moment, I use the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean')
signals = imp.fit_transform(array)
```

in which `array` is a numpy array of shape n_points x n_time_steps. It works fine but I get a deprecation warning which suggest I should use SimpleImpute from sklearn.impute. Hence I replaced those lines with the following:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean')
signals = imp.fit_transform(array)
```

but I get the following error on the last line:

> ValueError: 'X' and 'missing_values' types are expected to be both
>   numerical. Got X.dtype=float32 and  type(missing_values)=< class 'str'>.

If anybody has any idea on what is the cause of this error be glad if you let me know. I am using Python 3.6.7 with sklearn 0.20.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `array` contains missing values represented as np.NaN, you should use `np.Nan` as the argument to the constructor of SimpleImputer. That's the default argument, so  this works:

```
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not expect such a mismatch in keywords among the function of the same module. But now I know better!